# How can I get the product info in Stripe webhook (refund)

Tags: stripe-payments

I have Webhook, which configured in Developer tab on Stripe page.

It works well, but for example for refund, I have no info about product in response:

```
 {
  "id": "evt_1IsnzmJROm6awlUaq3rcFwr8",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2019-11-05",
  "created": 1621425325,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_1IsYZMJROm6awlUaER10QD3d",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 1750,
      "amount_captured": 1750,
      "amount_refunded": 1750,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "balance_transaction": "txn_1IsYZMJROm6awlUassUs5W6y",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": null,
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "71854",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "test@email-receiver.com",
        "name": "Test",
        "phone": null
      },
      "calculated_statement_descriptor": "TEST",
      "captured": true,
      "created": 1621366028,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": "cus_JVZiIhKIpCH9qh",
      "description": "Bla bla",
      "destination": null,
      "dispute": null,
      "disputed": false,
      "failure_code": null,
      "failure_message": null,
      "fraud_details": {
      },
      "invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "order": null,
      "outcome": {
        "network_status": "approved_by_network",
        "reason": null,
        "risk_level": "normal",
        "risk_score": 14,
        "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
        "type": "authorized"
      },
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": "pi_1IsYZMJROm6awlUaVsZOefRh",
      "payment_method": "pm_1IsYZJJROm6awlUasaBRHxzq",
      "payment_method_details": {
        "card": {
          "brand": "visa",
          "checks": {
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_postal_code_check": "pass",
            "cvc_check": "pass"
          },
          "country": "US",
          "exp_month": 1,
          "exp_year": 2023,
          "fingerprint": "QA94mAZK6R1nyB79",
          "funding": "credit",
          "installments": null,
          "last4": "4242",
          "network": "visa",
          "three_d_secure": null,
          "wallet": null
        },
        "type": "card"
      },
      "receipt_email": "test@email-receiver.com",
      "receipt_number": null,
      "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1Fg5jCJROm6awlas/ch_1IsYZMJROm6awlUaOI10QD3d/rcpt_JVZijS8cso7ks67hLGI705AvCCDOC8J",
      "refunded": true,
      "refunds": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "re_1IsnzlJROm6awlUa5vVlKl1T",
            "object": "refund",
            "amount": 1750,
            "balance_transaction": "txn_1IsnzlJROm6awlUaFZvKoHcE",
            "charge": "ch_1IsYZMJROm6awlUaER10QD3d",
            "created": 1621425325,
            "currency": "usd",
            "metadata": {
            },
            "payment_intent": "pi_1IsYZMJROm6awlUaVsZOefRh",
            "reason": "requested_by_customer",
            "receipt_number": null,
            "source_transfer_reversal": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_reversal": null
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1IsYZMJRlT6awlUaER10QD3d/refunds"
      },
      "review": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": null,
      "source_transfer": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    },
    "previous_attributes": {
      "amount_refunded": 0,
      "refunded": false,
      "refunds": {
        "data": [

        ],
        "total_count": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_Ga1TLn7TsaGIBg",
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "charge.refunded"
}
```

Comment: What product information are you looking for? If this is a refund for a regular charge/payment intent, it's not clear what you'd expect to find.

Comment: I want to get product_id, for which is refund.

Comment: Sure, but what product would you expect? Are you setting a product associated with the original payment somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in 'Products' tab, I have created few products, for which users pays.

Comment: Ok but how is that associated with the payment, here? Can you add a snippet to your question showing how you create payments? Are you using metadata? Are you using Checkout with line items? Are you using Subscriptions? If you just create Payment Intents with an `amount` there is no inherent link to a product, it's just a payment for an amount. Linking to a "Product" in that case is something you'd have to explicitly account for.